# Doble respuesta mientras estaba editando mi propia respuesta

Tags: soporte, bug

Me ha pasado ahora mismo una cosa extraña cuando he respondido es esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125235/6491).

Cuando la he respondido quería expandir un poco más la respuesta cuando de repente en la mitad de la edición me apareció la barra amarilla que alguien **más** ha respondido a la respuesta.

La he pulsado para ver la nueva respuesta, pero no ha aparecido ninguna nueva (hm.. raro pensé yo), pero cuando he terminado en editarlo ha aparecido dos respuesta mía, una sin la edición y la otra con:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A que se debe esto? ¿Bug? ¿Magia navideña?

Comment: Me ha ocurrido en un par de ocasiones, me parece se trata solo de un bug, no te asustes... :(

Comment: @Jorgesys - si tendría miedo por un bug... tendría que cambiarme de oficio ;)

Comment: Vi varias veces este error en MSE/MSO (y varios otros referidos a la notificación de nuevas respuestas). Siempre se trata de una carrera entre llamadas por AJAX que, en algunos casos, gana la que no tiene que ganar... Puede estar algo relacionado a Winter Bash, ya que todo funciona más lento con los sombreros. De todas formas, no recuerdo que lo hayan solucionado jamás.